# A algorithm about PHP decimal to binary

Tags: php

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2；
$c = 4;
$d = 8;
$e = 16;
$f = 32;
$g = 64;
   .
   .
   .
```

The above sequence is n to the power of 2,$n is the number of above a few in series and, if give you $n, using an algorithm to find the $n is by which a few together to get on it

Comment: Question need to be added more details like what you exactly trying to achieve? what is expected outcome etc...

Comment: do you want like this:- https://eval.in/751140

Comment: I put my question did some modification

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php or is it homework?

Comment: Of course not。。。

Comment: what's your expected out. I try to get your means, but with failure.

Comment: your words below the code is really hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get single bits (for you variables $a, $b, ...) with [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Example:
Checking which bits are set

```
<?php
$n = 21; //number received from somewhere

if ($n & 1 == 1) {
    echo "least significant bit is set";
}

if ($n & 2 == 2) {
    echo "second least significant bit is set";
}

if ($n & 5 == 5) {
    echo "third least and least significant bits are set";
}

if ($n & 3 == 1) {
    echo "least significant bit is set and second least significant bit is unset";
}
?>
```

Example2: Bitwise addition and multiplication

```
<?php
$n1 = 1 | 8 | 16; // 1 + 8 + 16 = 25
$n2 = 2 | 8; // 2 + 8 = 10

echo "$n1 and $n2\n"; // output: "25 and 10"
echo ($n1 | $n2) . "\n"; // bitwise addition 25 + 10, output: "27"
echo ($n1 & $n2) . "\n"; // bitwise multiplication 25 * 10, output: "8"
?>
```

Example3: this is what you need

pow(2, $i) produces in this case numbers 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., binary representation of these numbers are: 0000001, 00000010, 00000100, 00001000, ...

bitwise and operator makes zero bits where at least one operand has zero bits, so you can easily get whole number bit by bit

This is how bitwise and works: 1101 & 0100 = 0100, 1101 & 0010 = 0000

```
<?php
// get number from somewhere
$x = 27; // binary representation 00011011

// let's define maximum exponent of 2^$a (number of bits)
$a = 8; // 8 bit number, so it can be 0 - 255

$result = [];
$resIndex = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $a; $i++) {
    // here is the heart of algorithm - it has cancer, but it should work
    // by that cancer I mean calling three times pow isn't effective and I see other possible optimalisation, but I let it on you
    if ((pow(2, $i) & $x) > 0) {
        echo pow(2, $i) . "\n";  // prints "1", "2", "8", "16"
        $result[$resIndex] = pow(2, $i); // save it to array for later use
    }
}
```

Comment: What I need is the number and enter any more than a 2 n number of additive, can output the number

Comment: I can't help myself, I still think you need bitwise operations... Check the second example which I added if it's what you want.

Comment: I need this. Second example, If I give you $n2 ($n2 = 2 + 8), how could i get 2 and 8

Comment: That's the first example, but now I understand you. I'll try to create third example to show it to you, how to use it for your needs.

Comment: I tested the third example in sandbox and it works as you described in last comment

Comment: Yes,that's what I need.Thanks,but I just create accounts, reputation is not enough, I'm sorry I can't give you a score

Comment: Your welcome. And don't worry, you accepted the answer and I got the score.